# How to configure Komodo edit to work with virtualenv or rvm?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, rvm, virtualenv, komodo

Is it possible to configure `Komodo edit` to work with `virtualenv` and/or `rvm`? I'm on linux mint 12

Comment: What do you mean "configure to work"?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I mean `to detect libraries` on windows when you install lets say `PIL` via pipm and `import PIL` then komodo detects all the modules that `PIL` have and autocomplete your code, + you can run the code from komodo, but I'm not using `PyPm` on linux so it won't detect `PIL` or any other libraries because they are installed in virtualenv... I hope that i have clarified my question

Answer (score 1):

Use the context menu to setup [virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219630/virtualenv-and-komodo-ide-on-windows). Right-click on Project > Properties > Languages > Python > Additional Python Import Directories.

Use an alias in .profile to add support for [rvm](http://community.activestate.com/forum/does-komodo-support-rvm-or-not).

```
alias komodo='open -a "Komodo Edit"'
```

From there, type "rvm use ree( or rbx, or 1.9.1, or whichever version you want)."